# Data structure for quickly obtaining all axis-aligned rectangles completely within rectangular region

Tags: data-structures, computational-geometry, trees, intervals

I'm stuck on a homework assignment. There are $n$ axis aligned rectangles and we need to find a data structure of size $O(n \log^2 n)$ and query time $O(\log^3 n + k)$ that can give all rectangles completely contained in an axis-aligned query rectangle (where $k$ is the number of contained rectangles).

The course covered range-, priority search-, interval- and segment trees. Looking at the query time, I probably need to combine 2 or 3 trees but I don't know which ones or how exactly. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Don't need a full answer, just a hint might do it!